# How to print order of list and the index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, this is the output that I want  from the input:

```
Input:   
    5    
    4    
    3    
    7    
    6
```

```
Output:
    P[1]5
    P[2]4
    P[3]3
    P[4]7
    P[5]6
    Lowest Number = 3    
    Highest Number = 7
```

But I got this with my code

```
[P1] 4
[P2] 4
[P3] 4
[P4] 4
[P5] 4
Lowest Number = 3
Highest Number = 7
```

This is my code:

```
X = []
for i in range (0,5):
    X.append(int(input()))
for j in range (0,5):
    print("[P"+str(j+1)+"]", i)

print("Lowest Number = ",min(X))      
print("Highest Number = ",max(X))
```

I got a few questions:

1. Where do all the '4's come from?
2. Is there a way to remove the space between [P1] and 4 so it should be [P1]4 (from the wrong output) or [P1]5 (from the right output)?

Thank you.

Comment: Select index `j` from list `X`: `print("[P"+str(j+1)+"]", X[j])`? Check out [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), too.

Comment: because you are printing `i`, which is `4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to your code

```py
X = []
for i in range (0,5):
    X.append(int(input()))
for j in range (0,5):
    print("[P"+str(j+1)+"]", i)#there is the problem

print("Highest Number = ",max(X))
print("Lowest Number = ",min(X))
```

you are calling `i` instead of `X[j]`

Answer (score 1):

**ad 1.** You printed variable `i`, which has set to 4 as the last number of the first range. I recommand to use `enumerate` function and iterate trought the list `X`, which is a better practice, because you can change a length of `X`.

**ad 2.** Use a better way to control your output (.format, f-string since Python 3.6).

Here's example about .format:

```
X = []
for i in range (0,5):
    X.append(int(input()))

for no, number in enumerate(X, start=1):
    print("[P{0}]{1}".format(no, number))

print("Highest Number = {0}".format(max(X)))
print("Lowest Number = {0}".format(min(X)))
```

A here's example about f-string:

```
X = []
for i in range (0,5):
    X.append(int(input()))

for no, number in enumerate(X, start=1):
    print(f"[P{no}]{number}")

print(f"Highest Number = {max(X)}")
print(f"Lowest Number = {min(X)}")
```

For example, here's a quick review of formatting: https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/